# POST request returns "414 URI too long" - mwn (axios might be involved)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm maintaining a bot for Wikipedia using [npm mwbot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mwbot), but now I'm migrating to [mwn](https://github.com/siddharthvp/mwn). I'm experiencing some strange behaviour of mwn; that is, a POST request fails because of a 414 error.

Let's say you have some list of usernames from a wiki project and you want to check if any of the users is blocked from editing. This can be done by [mediawiki action API list=blocks](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bblocks) with the "bkusers" parameter specified with a pipe- (or "|"-) separated list of usernames, and bots can query 500 usernames with one API call. The following TypeScript code should do the job, but the relevant query fails because of 414. (Since it's a POST request, I have absolutely no idea why.)

```
import { mwn } from "mwn";

(async () => {

    const mw: mwn = await mwn.init({
        apiUrl: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
        username: 'YourBotUsername',
        password: 'YourBotPassword',
        userAgent: 'myCoolToolName 1.0 ([[link to bot user page or tool documentation]])'
    });

    interface DynamicObject {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        [key: string]: any
    }
    interface ApiResponseListLogeventsItem {
        logid: number,
        ns: number,
        title: string,
        pageid: number,
        logpage: number,
        params: DynamicObject,
        type: string,
        action: string,
        user: string,
        anon?: boolean,
        timestamp: string,
        comment: string
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
    interface ApiResponseListLogevents extends Array<ApiResponseListLogeventsItem> {}

    // Get 500 (5000 if you're a bot) usernames from the latest logs of account creation
    const response = await mw.continuedQuery({
        action: 'query',
        list: 'logevents',
        leprop: 'ids|title|timestamp',
        letype: 'newusers',
        lelimit: 'max',
    }, 1).then(res => res).catch(err => console.log(err.info));
    if (!response) return;
    const resLgev: ApiResponseListLogevents = response.filter((obj: DynamicObject) => obj && obj.query && obj.query.logevents).map(obj => obj.query && obj.query.logevents).flat();
    const users = resLgev.filter(obj => obj.title).map(obj => obj.title.replace(/^User:/, ''));
    console.log(users.length);

    // Check if any of the users is blocked
    const r = await mw.request({ // => Returns 414 'URI Too Long' although this is a POST request
        action: 'query',
        list: 'blocks',
        bklimit: 'max',
        bkusers: users.slice(0, 500).join('|'), // Pipe-separated list of users
        bkprop: 'user|timestamp|expiry|restrictions|flags',
        formatversion: '2'
    }, {method: 'POST'}).then(res => res).catch(err => console.log(err));

    if (!r || !r.query || !r.query.blocks) return console.log('!');
    console.log(r.query.blocks.length);

})();
```

The first half of the code isn't that important because it's just there to fetch some random usernames from the API. The problem is with mw.request(). An equivalent code with the mwbot framework works so this doesn't seem to be a server-side issue. I would appreciate any comments on what'd be wrong.

I don't know if this is relevant but the issue might come from [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), which mwn uses for HTTP requests. Yesterday I wrote a function to scrape a webpage, and at first used axios. But it constantly spit "Package subpath './lib/defaults' is not defined by 'exports'" error so I uninstalled it and am now using node:https to fetch a website's html. But as I just said above, I don't know if this is relevant in any way.

Comment: Did you try to capture requests from both packages and compare them?

Comment: Even if it's POST request the users list is passed in a query parameter so depending on the length of user names it might exceed the maximum of the URL length. Did you try to decrease the number of users passed in one request?

Comment: Just tried the same code with both mwn and mwbot, run at the same time (to make sure that we have the same list of usernames). With mwn, users.slice(0, 100).join('|') worked. But when I had given it a try with 50 earlier, that returned a 414 too... With mwbot, users.slice(0, 500).join('|') works every time. I don't quite get it :(

Comment: Did you compare the whole requests in dev tools or some network sniffer?